# Collision detection in R

Tags: r, igraph, quadtree

I have a matrix of positions returned from any of the igraph layouts, e.g.,

```
layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold(g)
```

This just has a set of points:

```
            [,1]        [,2]
[1,]  22.0952841 -25.0292619
[2,]  14.0612662  13.0353858
[3,]  54.0149021  12.5197793
[4,]  27.5570371 -25.2109356
```

Does someone know of a collision detection package that I can feed this into and get back similar matrix with points moved so that there is no collisions? (i.e., given some min dist)

Comment: check this one out http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud/wordcloud.pdf

Comment: not quite :(, the preservation (as much as possible) of the original coordinates is needed.